# Left join is not working for complex query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, left-join

I have very complex linq query which is working fine for inner join, i.e., without `z_temp.DefaultIfEmpty()`. But when I use this for left join, The query is not yielding results.

```
var q = from x in db.EmployeesList
        where x.EmployeesListStartDate >= startDate && x.EmployeesListStartDate <= endDate
        join y in db.Survey on x.Survey.SurveyID equals y.SurveyID
        join z in
                (from a in db.Commit
                 join b in
                         (from commit in db.Commit
                          where
                            commit.CommitListID != null &&
                            commit.CommitType.ToUpper() != "PREVIEW"
                          group commit by new
                          {
                              commit.CommitListID
                          } into g
                          select new
                          {
                              CommitListID = (Int32?)g.Key.CommitListID,
                              CommitId = (Int32?)g.Max(p => p.CommitId)
                          })
                       on new { a.CommitListID, a.CommitId }
                   equals new { b.CommitListID, CommitId = (Int32)b.CommitId }
                 select new
                 {
                     CommitListID = (Int32?)a.CommitListID,
                     CommitUsername= a.CommitUsername,
                     CommitStartDateTime=a.CommitStartDateTime,
                     CommitType=a.CommitType,
                     CommitSuccessCount=a.CommitSuccessCount
                 }) on new { EmployeesListID = x.EmployeesListID } equals new { EmployeesListID = (Int32)z.CommitListID }
                 into z_temp
        from _z in z_temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new CustomEmployeesList
        {
            SurveyId = x.Survey.SurveyID != null ? (int)x.Survey.SurveyID : 0,
            EmployeesListId = x.EmployeesListID != null ? (int)x.EmployeesListID : 0,
            EmployeesListName = x.EmployeesListName,
            SpecificMessage = x.SpecificMessage,
            ListCriteria = x.ListCriteria,
            Channel = x.Channel,
            EmployeesListStartDate = (DateTime)x.EmployeesListStartDate,
            EmployeesListEndDate = (DateTime)x.EmployeesListEndDate,
            Records = x.Records != null ? (int)x.Records : 0,
            QueryId = x.AppSqlQueries.QueryId != null ? (int)x.AppSqlQueries.QueryId : 0,
            //AuditId = (Int32?)x.AuditEntry.AuditId,
            StatusCommonCode = x.CommonCode.CommonCodeId != null ? (int)x.CommonCode.CommonCodeId : 0,
            SurveyName = y.SurveyName,
            LastCommitDateTime = _z.CommitStartDateTime.HasValue ? (DateTime)_z.CommitStartDateTime : DateTime.MinValue,
            LastCommitType = _z.CommitType != null ? _z.CommitType : "",
            LastCommitUsername = _z.CommitUsername != null ? _z.CommitUsername : "",
            LastCommitCount = _z.CommitSuccessCount.HasValue ? (int)_z.CommitSuccessCount : 0
        };
```

This is returning no results and
I am getting this exception message while viewing results in debug mode:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[<>f_*AnonymousType351[<>f*_AnonymousType35%5bSystem.Nullable1[System.Int32],System.String,System.Nullable1%5bSystem.DateTime%5d,System.String,System.Nullable`1%5bSystem.Int32%5d%5d%5d">System.Nullable1[System.Int32],System.String,System.Nullable1[System.DateTime],System.String,System.Nullable1[System.Int32]]]
>   DefaultIfEmpty[<>f__AnonymousType35' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

Can anyone suggest the where the problem would be, this would be really helpful!

Comment: The error seems to come from this line: `from _z in z_temp.DefaultIfEmpty()` What are you trying to do there?

Comment: Yes I want to left join with the EmployeesList table

Comment: assuming the complexity of your database you should use Entity Framework with linq to entity. I have never seen nothing like that before..

Comment: Yes, I am using Entity Framework and this is linq to entity. And this query is a very complex using join on 3 times on two tables, however the query is executing successfully normally i.e., for inner join. But when I want to left join with "EmployeesList" i.e., in Linq adding - "into z_temp from _z in z_temp.DefaultIfEmpty()", I am getting the error. I have checked all the null values and make sure. But don't know why I am not getting results ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
 from _z in z_temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Calling `DefaultIfEmpty()` will return `null` if no rows matches the join. Ok, you a left join, but you have to test if `_z` is `null` before access its members:

```
 ...
 LastCommitDateTime = _z == null ? DateTime.MinValue : (_z.CommitStartDateTime.HasValue ? (DateTime)_z.CommitStartDateTime : DateTime.MinValue),
 LastCommitType = _z == null ? "" : (_z.CommitType != null ? _z.CommitType : ""),
 ...
 etc.
```

A more elegant alternative is create a class that defines the fields you want and call `_z.DefaultIfEmpty(new ZRow())`, so you don't need to test if `_z` is null every time you need it. But in this case you'll need to change the `select` that produces the result for `z_temp` and replace it to `select new ZRow(a.CommitListID, etc..)`. Not a big deal.

Comment: The first method of checking  _z==null  make sense for the possible cause for the error, when I execute I got the same error.

And interestingly the second one has given me the error,
 
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[SA.Repository.CampaignManagement.CampaignManagementRepository+ZRow] DefaultIfEmpty[ZRow](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[SA.Repository.CampaignManagement.CampaignManagementRepository+ZRow], ZRow)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I dont know what to do ?